# jetty HTTP2Client jar missing

Tags: java, jar, jetty, jetty-9, http2

I've downloaded the latest (9.3.7.v20160115) Jetty from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/dist/jetty-distribution-9.3.7.v20160115.zip).

Accourding to the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http2.html), the HTTP/2 has 4 sub-projects, one is http2-client.

I'm unable to find it. The only jars I have in http2 are:

- http2-common-9.3.7.v20160115.jar
- http2-hpack-9.3.7.v20160115.jar
- http2-server-9.3.7.v20160115.jar

What has happened with http2-client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Jetty components are available on Global Maven Repository system.

Here's the components belonging to [org.eclipse.jetty.http2](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.eclipse.jetty.http2), along with the [http2-client](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty.http2%22%20AND%20a%3A%22http2-client%22) you are looking for.

Since there is nothing in the jetty-distribution that uses the http2-client (and associated alpn-client), and there is no way to use the http2-client through the server / webapp classloader isolation, its highly unlikely that it will show up on the jetty-distribution.

If you intend to use it standalone (not from a java web/app server), then use the components from maven central.

If your intention is to use it from a jetty server instance, you'll want to copy the components into place in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory for your webapp (be aware that you should have your http2-client and jetty server versions in lockstep if you attempt to do this, as you can potentially share many utility/io/http classes from jetty server classloader itself)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479706) and [GitHub issue](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/237) this is a bug.